# SNMPD active but got errors in status

Tags: debian, snmp, snmpd

I've got a server running on Debian 8 with snmp service working on it.
However when I get the status of snmpd, it says that it is running but with errors:

`service snmpd status`:

```
snmpd[30734]: Cannot statfs /sys/kernel/security
              : Permission denied
snmpd[30734]: Cannot statfs /sys/kernel/config
              : Permission denied
```

I need it to supervise this server with Zabbix

---

UPDATE:

SNMPDOTS in /etc/default/snmpd:

```
SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -I -smux -p /var/run/snmpd.pid -c /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf'
```

---

UPDATE:
This is the error message I'm getting (full):

```
root@ns3726041:~# service snmpd status
● snmpd.service - LSB: SNMP agents
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/snmpd)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-09-20 16:58:03 CEST; 18min ago
  Process: 9221 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/snmpd stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9227 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/snmpd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/snmpd.service
           └─9233 /usr/sbin/snmpd -Ls3d -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -I -smux -p /var/run/snmpd.pid -c /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

Sep 20 17:16:40 ns3726041.ip-149-202-220.eu snmpd[9233]: Cannot statfs /sys/kernel/config
                                                         : Permission denied
Sep 20 17:16:40 ns3726041.ip-149-202-220.eu snmpd[9233]: Connection from UDP: [10.0.1.30]:64202->[11.11.150.101]:161
Sep 20 17:16:40 ns3726041.ip-149-202-220.eu snmpd[9233]: Connection from UDP: [10.0.1.30]:64203->[11.11.150.101]:161
Sep 20 17:16:40 ns3726041.ip-149-202-220.eu snmpd[9233]: Connection from UDP: [10.0.1.30]:64205->[11.11.150.101]:161
Sep 20 17:16:40 ns3726041.ip-149-202-220.eu snmpd[9233]: Connection from UDP: [10.0.1.30]:64208->[11.11.150.101]:161
Sep 20 17:16:49 ns3726041.ip-149-202-220.eu snmpd[9233]: Connection from UDP: [10.0.1.30]:64255->[11.11.150.101]:161
Sep 20 17:16:49 ns3726041.ip-149-202-220.eu snmpd[9233]: Connection from UDP: [10.0.1.30]:64256->[11.11.150.101]:161
Sep 20 17:16:49 ns3726041.ip-149-202-220.eu snmpd[9233]: Connection from UDP: [10.0.1.30]:64257->[11.11.150.101]:161
Sep 20 17:16:49 ns3726041.ip-149-202-220.eu snmpd[9233]: Cannot statfs /sys/kernel/security
                                                         : Permission denied
Sep 20 17:16:49 ns3726041.ip-149-202-220.eu snmpd[9233]: Cannot statfs /sys/kernel/config
                                                         : Permission denied
```

---

In the /proc/mounts:

```
root@sva2:~# cat /proc/mounts 
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
none /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
none /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
none /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=1977892k,nr_inodes=494473,mode=755 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
/dev/sda1 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime 0 0
none /var/run tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
none /var/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
none /lib/init/rw tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /home ext4 rw,relatime,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
11.11.150.70:/storage/nfs/eco-visio /home/www2 nfs rw,noatime,nodiratime,vers=3,rsize=262144,wsize=262144,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=11.11.150.70,mountvers=3,mountproto=tcp,addr=11.11.150.70 0 0
```

Comment: you need to do this command as admin retry after a sudo -i

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need a session as admin to do this command ;) :

```
sudo -i  //login as admin if the user are in group of sudo
service snmpd status   //no problem 

#backup the file before

SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -g snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid'
```

Comment: @Guillaume Niwanet isn't at root but pseudo root a user who are in the group of sudoers no loged as root. But may be is a other problem check the /var/logs/snmpd ..., regards.

Comment: I will try, thanks. Moreover in /var/log/rsyslog I have the exact same error message

Comment: try a cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe > result.txt It's creating a file that's causing the problem. paste the secure ref here.

Comment: Can you please copy/paste the SNMPDOPTS line of your /etc/default/snmpd file ?

Comment: I don't have this folder /debug/, which tool do I need to install?

Comment: cos i am on debian :( may be the arch isn't the same.

Comment: @Guillaume Niwanet And if you do: sudo  /etc/init.d/snmpd status you got the same error? i want to known if is an "systemd service got a problem or snmpd".

Comment: Yes, I do :( I'm adding the full error message in the question

Comment: @Guillaume Niwanet Try to replace your SNMPDOPTS by this one on the "POST principal copy/paste" and try do : sudo /etc/init.d/snmpd reload  (for reloading configuration) and sudo /etc/init.d/snmpd restart and if the error still beeing on the output.

Comment: Thanks for the SNMPOPTS. Please also provide the content of your /proc/mounts. I may have an idea but need to check something before.

Comment: I added it to the description